# Dependent or independent samples (possibility of using both in a regression analysis?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, sampling, sample, biostatistics

What happens if in my data set I have 95% independent samples, but 5% are dependent samples? does this effect which tests I can run?

Also, I guess a good example is it is like having 3 outcomes to an apple: worms present, mites present & lice present. Using variables such as the weight of an apple, length, and age could I just run 3 models to look at the parasites present or is there a way to test them all in the same model?

Comment: Please explain what your opening line means: what is an "independent sample" and what is a "dependent sample"?  Which "tests" are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: Sorry I think related samples is a better descriptor, related sample = Each apple/subject has 2 or more repeated measures and independent sample = Each apple/subject has 1 measure only.

Comment: Initially, I want to run a glm with binomial error bars but hopefully move this anova.gam after success. 

The issue is looking at these 3 parasites in the same model means in cases where they are found in the same apple 1 might of had an effect on the other but the crossover was rather rare but i feel like this may effect my results.

Comment: (i am not actually working with apples but this is a good example i hope)